# Pixel-based regression using xarray has incorrect P-value, but everything else is correct

Tags: python, raster, pixel, xarray, scipy

I am using the code from [this website](https://hrishichandanpurkar.blogspot.com/2017/09/vectorized-functions-for-correlation.html) to perform a regression on each pixel of an image time-series of rain and NDVI. The code works for everything, that is the outputs match the outputs of scipy, for everything but the p values.

From the code:

- Correlation = -0.2676303
- Slope = -0.00026039145
- Intercept = 0.90573066
- P-value = 1.7591585784927986

From Scipy:

- Correlation = -0.2676302926936089
- Slope = -0.0002603914165868962
- Intercept = 0.9057306214877914
- P-value = 0.24084146815441976

There are 21 images of both rainfall and NDVI, one per year, with a shape of 4296x11009.

Here is the code to print the values:

```
cov,cor,slope,intercept,pval,stderr = lag_linregress_3D(x,y)
print(cor[1000,2000].data, pval[1000,2000].data, slope[1000,2000].data, intercept[1000,2000].data, stderr[1000,2000].data)
from  scipy import stats, signal
ans = stats.linregress(rain21[:,1000,2000],ndvi21[:,1000,2000])
print('stats.linregress() output:\n',ans.rvalue, ans.pvalue, ans.slope, ans.intercept, ans.stderr)
```

Comment: Could you maybe provide a minimal code example that shows that the p-values are different for the two methods for some made-up/dummy/fake data?